# Nginx proxy to Apache - resolve HTTP ORIGIN

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a server setup with nginx serving static content and proxy all PHP/dynamic requests to apache on 127.0.0.1

I'm building an API for my databases, and I need to allow clients by their origin (domain name), rather than just IP. Based on CORS rules.

So when I send an HTTP header `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.client-requesting.myapi.com");` from my API server, I have to tell it which origin I allow, otherwise client side requests won't work to my API due to same-origin policy.

The question is how can I know which domain name (if any) called my API?

What should be the nginx and apache configuration to pass the origin parameter? I tried to google, and all I found is some possible solution with mod_rpaf, but I wanted to be sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same-Origin-Policy and CORS, as far as i understood, are server-based, not client-based, except when you have your API-Access-Scripts deployed on `www.client-requesting.myapi.com`.

so, what you are allowing with CORS is NOT, wherefrom API-Requests are allowed, but from which source an external script might access your API, e.g.

- API is at api.my.com (SAME ORIGIN)
- JS is at scripts.my.com (Access-Control-Allow-Origin: scripts.my.com)